# Creating multiple resources with a single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have a model called `UserPrice` and I want to let users be able to create many of the same resources on one form using just the `UserPrice` model.

### Success

**Working Code:** ( this code will create x amount of user_prices but will not show error messages/validate or reject if certain fields are blank.)

```
class UserPricesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user_prices = Array.new(5) { UserPrice.new }
  end

  def create_multiple
    @user_prices = params[:user_prices].values.collect { |user_price| UserPrice.new(user_price) }
    if @user_prices.all?(&:valid?)
      @user_prices.each(&:save!)
      redirect_to :action => :new, :notice => "Successfully created product."
     else
        redirect_to :back, :notice => "Error."
    end
  end


  resources :user_prices do
    post :create_multiple, :on => :collection
  end

 <%= form_tag create_multiple_user_prices_path, :method => :post do %>
    <% @user_prices.each_with_index do |user_price, index| %>
       <%= fields_for "user_prices[#{index}]", user_price do |up| %>
         <%= render "add_user_price_fields", :f => up %>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag "Done" %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your controller method `create_multiple` where you're only creating one object.

You should try something like this:

```
def create_multiple
  @user_prices = params[:user_prices].values.collect { |up| UserPrice.new(up) }
  if @user_prices.all?(&:valid?)
    @user_prices.each(&:save!)
    format.html { redirect_to(:back, :notice => 'Successfully added prices.') }
    format.xml { head :ok }
  else
    # ...
```

[Source](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=11859#p11859)

Comment: Thanks I updated my question. I am still having issues but I know this is the right direction. Take a look at my new code now. What do you think?